# I need to add a predelay to jQuery UI Tooltips but can't seem to figure it out

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tooltip

I need to add a predelay on my jQuery UI tooltips.  I am using the most recent version (1.9) and would like the tips to open 2 seconds after they are hovered over.

I am calling the tips in my header using:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( document ).tooltip({ predelay:2000,});   
    });
</script>
```

But when they are fired, they do not have any delay whatsoever... any help?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

use this

```
$( "#elementid" ).tooltip({
  show: {
    effect: "slideDown",
    delay: 250
  }
});
```

Comment: If the effect isn't important, `$( "#elementid" ).tooltip({show:{delay: 2500}});` is enough.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem but finally came up with this solution:

```
var opendelay = 500;
var closedelay = 500;
var target = $('.selector');
target.tooltip({ /* ... */ });
target.off('mouseover mouseout');
target.on('mouseover', function(event) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    clearTimeout(target.data('closeTimeoutId'));
    target.data('openTimeoutId', setTimeout(function() { target.tooltip('open'); }, opendelay));
});
target.on('mouseout', function(event) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    clearTimeout(target.data('openTimeoutId'));
    target.data('closeTimeoutId', setTimeout(function() { target.tooltip('close'); }, closedelay));
});
```

Essentially what it does is:

- Disable the default onMouseOver event for the tooltip
- Add a new mouseOver-event for the tooltip which is delayed using setTimeout()
- Add a new mouseOut-event which cancels the timeout (this prevents the tooltip from showing in case the mouse left the target area already before the delay ellapsed)
- BONUS: It also adds a "closedelay" similar to the "opendelay" aka "predelay" using the same technique
- `event.stopImmediatePropagation();` is only needed in some cases. eg. if you want the tooltip-element to stay visible while hovering IT (after it opened). If you want this, register the same hover events on the tooltip: `target.tooltip({ open: function (event, ui) { ui.tooltip.hover(..., ...); } });`
- p.s. you can also chain several of these calls like `on` and `off`.
- It *might* be possible to replace `target` inside the event-functions by `this` or `$(this)`. But i'm not sure and haven't tried it; might not work after all.
- If you don't need the closeDelay simply delete the lines containing `closeTimeoutId` or `closedelay` and remove `mouseout` in `target.off('mouseover mouseout');` or set it to 0
- The same goes for if you don't need openDelay ... just the other way around

Answer (score 0):

IE has issues with dangling commas, perhaps try removing that and seeing if that helps:

```
$( document ).tooltip({ delay:2000 });
```

Comment: This didn't work for me.. I was able to see the tooltip though, but the delay value made no difference. The accepted answer correctly incorporates the delay.